# Extra terms in the boundary of the simplex

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to calculate a very simple boundary of a 4-simplex which i know is $0$, but I am getting extra terms.

Trying to see that $$\delta_3\delta_4([x_1,\dots,x_5]) = 0.$$

Note that it is already known $\delta_n\delta_{n -1}=0$, I am just going through and example to convince myself

Recall $\delta_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n+1}(-1)^i [v_1, \dots \hat{v_i},\dots,v_n]$ where $\hat{v_i}$ is omitted.

$\delta_4([v_1,\dots,v_5)] = [v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5] + \dots + [v_1,\dots,v_5]$.

Now for some reason, when i calculate $\delta_3([v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5])$, I get $[v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5]$ as one of the summands because the sum omits $v_1$ in the first iteration, so i Have a $4-$simplex in a boundary computation of $\delta_3$. And nothing else was cancelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when i calculate $\delta_3([v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5])$, I get $[v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5]$ as one of the summands because the sum omits $v_1$ in the first iteration

This is not how $\delta_3$ acts on $[v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5]$. Essentially, you do not care about the indices themselves, but just their ordering. You can imagine writing $[v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5]=[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$ and applying the formula to that. To write out this case,

$$\delta_3([v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5])=[v_3,v_4,v_5]-[v_2,v_4,v_5]+[v_2,v_3,v_5]-[v_2,v_3,v_4].$$